# jQuery get the actual class of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This gives me a list of classes the clicked element has:

```
$("#nav li ul li").click(function(e){
        var cla=$(this).attr('class');
});
```

I only want the actual class written beside the element, I don't want the others.

Comment: *I only want the actual class written beside the element, I don't want the others.* ???

Comment: There is no "actual class", they are all equally valid. Do you mean the id? The first class maybe?

Comment: I mean: the element may have other classes attributed to it by parents. I want the class written right inside the clicked li tag.

Comment: *the element may have other classes attributed to it by parents. I want the class written right inside the clicked li tag* ????????

Comment: An element does not inherit classes from its parent. It's really not clear what you mean. If you have `<div class="foo bar" ...` then the element has two classes, `foo` and `bar`. `$(this).attr('class')` will exactly return the value of the `class` attribute that you see in the HTML (and the ones added via JS). Adding an example of the HTML and what data you want to get from it would certainly help to understand the problem.

Comment: Quoting the OP and adding question marks is rude and fairly useless. Please try explaining what you don't understand and asking for clarity.

Comment: OP, perhaps an example might be useful, since we can't seem to understand you.  What should `cla` be, if the `li` is `<li class="one two three">Something</li>`

Answer (score 1):

This will provide the first class in the list of classes on an element.

```
$("#nav li ul li").click(function(e){
    var cla= this.className.split(/[ \n\r\t\f]/g)[0];
});
```

**Example**

```
<li class="one two three">Something</li>
```

Returns one

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/kfL9X/2/

If you are after only classes on the `li` you may improperly assuming how `.attr('class')` is working.  Since it will only return classes on the selected element.

For example given this HTML:

```
<ul class="other clazzes">
    <li class="one two three">Something</li>
</ul>
```

The following Javascript would alert:

```
$("ul li").click(function(e){
    alert(this.className); //alerts one two three, no parent classes
});
```

Comment: nuh uh. `.split(" ")[0]` should be `.split(" ").map($.trim);`.

Comment: Why not just `this.className`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I think he only wants the first class

Comment: Right, but why `$(this).attr('class')`? Seems like overkill.

Comment: should be `.split(/ \n\r\t\f/g)`, spaces aren't the only characters that can separate CSS classes.

Comment: @zzzzBov +1 grrrreat catch!

Comment: @zzzzBov Tried the regex it wasn't working, but `\s` did, would that handle everything?  With your regex: http://jsfiddle.net/kfL9X/1/

Comment: @KevinBowersox, [`\s` is actually too permissive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), and is not correct.

Comment: @zzzBov Did I implement your regex correctly?  I usually avoid them when it comes to markup, I just have read too many nightmares about markup + regex, I could be assuming wrong though.

Comment: @KevinBowersox, I'm an idiot, I forgot to use braces: `/[ \n\r\t\f]/g` is the right regex